# Returning 2 tables after a $http.post query in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I feel like it's a very simple question but i'm not sure about the syntax.
I do a $http.post query in my javascript file :

```
$http.post('server.php', {"data" : cleTexte, "serverFlag" : 2})
            .success(function(data, status) 
            {
                console.log(data);
                grantTable = data; 
            }
```

The php file is returning a table after a SQL query :

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT grantAmount FROM granttoassociation WHERE HEX(grantReceiver) = '$key' ");
while($rs = $result->fetch()) {
        if ($outp != "") {
            array_push($outp,$rs["grantAmount"]);
        }
}

$outp =json_encode($outp);
echo($outp);
```

And, as you can see, the result is affected to grantTable in the javascript file.
It's working fine, however, i would like to have TWO tables. The second table would be obtained after a second SQL query in the php file. The final result in the javascript file should be looking like :

```
$http.post('server.php', {"data" : cleTexte, "serverFlag" : 2})
            .success(function(data, status) 
            {
                console.log(data);
                grantTable = data...
                grantYear = data...
            }
```

Houw should i do that ?

The second SQL query would be something like :

```
"SELECT grantYear FROM granttoassociation WHERE HEX(grantReceiver) = '$key' "
```

Comment: and you need to make a SQL query, a php complex cmbination of two querys, or neew two make two $http in angular. Exact problem is?, i cant understand it

Comment: If i make 2 SQL request in the php file, the $http.post query will return 2 table somehow.

How do I access the 2 table in my javascript file ? Should i write    `grantTable = data.table1;` or something like that... ?

Comment: You need to create an object from php, to contain the first and the second table of SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to run something like

```
"SELECT grantYear, grantAmount FROM granttoassociation WHERE HEX(grantReceiver) = 'yourkey' "
```

Beware [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) though and use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to pass the parameters or [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/ro/book.mysqli.php).

In your javascript you can iterate data and `.push` the respective columns to the object you want to hold it in

```
function(data, status)
{
    console.log(data);
    grantTable = [];
    grantYear = [];
    for (var index in data) {
        grantTable.push(data[index]["grantAmount"]);
        grantYear.push(data[index]["grantYear"]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks !
What should the line `array_push($outp,$rs...` should look like though ?

Comment: I do not have the means to test it, but I think something like this would suit your needs array_push($outp,array("grantAmount" => $rs["grantAmount"], "grantYear" => $rs["grantYear"])); since the JS code expects an array having the corresponding indices.